# Auth0 MFA Guardian app.I get an error when i press "allow_button" in the push notification

Tags: auth0

I get an error when i press "allow button" in the push notification.
In auth0 logs this error appear:

Type    OTP Auth failed
Description Guardian - Second factor verification failed: RSA challenge validation failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that in the mobile phone, i had deactivate the option "automatic time zone and auto date/time" when i activated this option, the login works.